# Error with discord.js when typing message.channel.send

Tags: node.js, discord.js

**Hi there!** I am new to discord.js, I made a basic code, it looks like this

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'rules') {
    message.channel.send('My Message')
  }
});

client.login('token i have here');
```

but i keep getting this error.

```
Logged in as Name Logos <3#5407!
/home/runner/djs-namelogos/index.js:10
    message.channel.send('My Message')
    ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto [voxtool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15441245/voxtool)'s answer. The message event is an arrow function which takes a parameter of the message object. You have defined this object to be `msg` as such

```
client.on('message', msg => { ...
```

Since you pass in `msg`, you must use `msg.channel.send()`

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'rules') {
    msg.channel.send('My Message')
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, it says 'message is not defined'. Try

```
msg.channel.send('My Message')
```

and it should be fine.